# Using ORDER function in MDX with T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, mdx, olap-cube

I created query in MDX for OLAP cube with T-SQL and now I need sort data by the second column. Default the table is sort by first column. How can I sort by "Income" value? This is my query:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[DateFilter] AS 
    Cdate([Date.H_Date].CurrentMember.MemberValue) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Average] AS 
    [Measures].[Price] / [Measures].[Covers SUM] 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Average]
   ,[Measures].[Covers SUM]
   ,[Measures].[Price]
  }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME]
   ,[MEMBER_CAPTION]
   ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    Filter
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        CrossJoin
        (
          [Date].[H_Date].[Month].ALLMEMBERS
         ,[Waiter].[WaiterName].[WaiterName].ALLMEMBERS
        )
       ,{
          [Measures].[Average]
         ,[Measures].[Covers SUM]
         ,[Measures].[Price]
        }
      )
     ,
          Dateadd
          ("m"
           ,-1
           ,Dateadd
            ("m"
             ,Datediff
              ("m"
               ,Cdate(36526)
               ,Now()
              )
             ,Cdate(36526)
            )
          )
        <= 
          [Measures].[DateFilter]
      AND 
          [Measures].[DateFilter]
        < 
          Dateadd
          ("m"
           ,0
           ,Dateadd
            ("m"
             ,Datediff
              ("m"
               ,Cdate(36526)
               ,Now()
              )
             ,Cdate(36526)
            )
          )
    )
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    [MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME]
   ,[MEMBER_CAPTION]
   ON ROWS
FROM [YouCube];
```

Btw I use filter function by date and it little complicated my query so I have trouble with add sort function by "Income" value.

Comment: which tool generated your script? Excel? (the solve_orders included are the default solve orders which xl doesn't usually bother with but the boiler plate dimension properties are usually included in an xl script). Or is it taken from profiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add [ORDER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145587.aspx) to your set.

```
ORDER(
Filter(NonEmpty(CROSSJOIN([Date].[H_Date].[Month].AllMembers,
                                                    [Waiter].[WaiterName].[WaiterName].AllMembers),
                                                    {[Measures].[Average],[Measures].[Covers SUM],[Measures].[Price]}),
                                                    DATEADD("m",-1,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m",CDate(36526),NOW()),CDate(36526))) <= [Measures].[DateFilter] AND [Measures].[DateFilter] < DATEADD("m",0,DATEADD("m",DATEDIFF("m",CDate(36526),NOW()),CDate(36526)))) 
,[Measures].[Income])
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you very much. I forgot to add info that I'm beginner in MDX and name "Income" is alias of "Covers SUM" exactly. Thx.